# Refresh resource query on click in angular factory?

Tags: angularjs, ngresource

i am starting to learn angularJS and i am stuck figuring out how to pass  a variable to a factory and refresh the resource on a click event.

Specifically i don't know how to pass the search variable from the form field to the factory, passing it instead of the hardcoded '???' into params: {query:'???'} ... Then, on submit the resource should be fetched again with that search parameter... i tried to use "searchterms" variable in there but it outputs "searchterm" undefined in the console.

```
    <html ng-app="notmuchApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>notmuch sinatra</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-resource.js"></script>
  <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js"></script>
    <script>

  var notmuchApp = angular.module('notmuchApp', ['ui.bootstrap','ngResource']);
  notmuchApp.controller('handleSearch', ['$scope', 'getSearch',
    function ($scope, getSearch) {
        $scope.searchresults = getSearch.query();
    }]);

  notmuchApp.factory('getSearch', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/notmuch/search', {}, {
        query: { method: 'GET', params: {query:'???'}, isArray: true },
    })
});

  </script>
  </head>
 <body >
  <div ng-controller="handleSearch">
  <form ng-submit="getSearch">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchterm"> 
    <input type="submit" value="Search">
  </form>
    Results:
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="searchresult in searchresults">
         {{searchresult.date_relative}} {{searchresult.authors}} {{searchresult.subject}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

commonly, your factory would not return the result directly, but a "service" object that has a "getSearch" method:

```
  notmuchApp.controller('handleSearch', ['$scope', 'SearchService',
  function ($scope, SearchService) {
      SearchService.getSearch("aaa","bb").then(
        function(results) {
          $scope.searchresults = results;
        },
        function(error) {
          // display error message
        }
      );
  }]);

notmuchApp.factory('SearchService', function ($resource) {
  return {
    getSearch : function(param_a, param_b) {
        // do your ajax with param a and b
        return results
    }
});
```

also, you are in the world of asynchronous execution, so i took the liberty to change your code from "$scope.results = getResults()" to properly dealing with promises (plus error handling).